# Python - Converting nested list into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a nested list , how do I convert this into a dictionary

```
data = [["Employee","Salary","Age","Gender"],["001",1200,25,"M"],["002",1300,28,"M"],["003",1400,32,"M"],["004",1700,44,"F"]]
```

where the dictionary should read the below

```
dict = {'Employee':['001','002','003','004'],'Salary':[1200,1300,1400,1700],'Age':[25,28,32,44],'Gender':['M','M','M','F']}
```

I have tried to change into Pandas DataFrame and converted that into dictionary. 
But I am looking for a direct conversion from list into dictionary

Will appreciate your kind help. Expecting answers in Python 3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to use `zip`, which iterates through *i* th element of each list sequentially:

```
data = [["Employee","Salary","Age","Gender"],
        ["001",1200,25,"M"],
        ["002",1300,28,"M"],
        ["003",1400,32,"M"],
        ["004",1700,44,"F"]]

d = {k: v for k, *v in zip(*data)}
```

Unpacking via `*v`, as suggested by @Jean-FrançoisFabre, ensures your values are lists.

**Result**

```
{'Age': [25, 28, 32, 44],
 'Employee': ['001', '002', '003', '004'],
 'Gender': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'F'],
 'Salary': [1200, 1300, 1400, 1700]}
```

Another way is to use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0]).to_dict('list')

# {'Age': [25, 28, 32, 44],
#  'Employee': ['001', '002', '003', '004'],
#  'Gender': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'F'],
#  'Salary': [1200, 1300, 1400, 1700]}
```